# Model evaluates to nil if declared within 'if' block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that has a model `chart`, and a `chart` has a `datasource`. A `datasource` may have many `datapoints`. In my `chart create` method I have the following line:

```
@chart = Chart.new(chart_params)
@chart.datasource = Datasource.find_by_id(2)
@chart.save
```

This works fine - although it's not what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
if @chart.id == 2
      @chart.datasource = Datasource.find_by_id(2)
      @chart.save
end
```

When I do that, however, I get `NoMethodError in Charts#show`

`undefined method 'datapoints' for nil:NilClass`

The error in my `Charts#show` is generated starting with:

```
<% @chart.datasource.datapoints.each do |c| %>
          dates.push( "<%= c.date %>" )
          counts.push( <%= c.count %> )
<% end %>
```

Remember, this works perfectly fine if I hard-code the datasource id outside of an if block, wondering what could be causing this.

Comment: Have you tried `Datasource.find(2)`?

Comment: @Dawcars, yes I have and it gives me the same error. For some reason @chart.datasource is nil. But only if declared within the `if`.

Comment: Are you sure you have a chart with id==2?

Comment: yes. The chart is not nil, just the datasource within it.

Comment: Have you got a data source with id = 2

Comment: yep. Again - all of this code works fine without the `if`

Comment: in the broken block do you do `@chart = Chart.new(chart_params)`?

Comment: ^ no, the point of the code is to create a new chart, then, depending on the id, add a datasource to it.

Comment: are you sure you hit the inside of the if statement?

Comment: If you are creating a chart, surely it will not get an id until it is saved, so your if block will never get called.

Comment: @Dawcars, right you are. Just called save before the block and it works perfectly - thanks all. If you want to add an answer I will +1 and give it a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a chart it will not get an id until it is saved. Your if block will never get called until you have an id. That means your if block will never get called unless you save first.